# SIM900 module connects then disconnects from carrier soon after

Tags: softwareserial, gsm

I have an Arduino Mega 2560 with an ESP8266 built into it, and a SIM900 shield, which I am building a project with.

The shield is powered by an external adjustable 3-12V, 2A supply set at 6V so power is not an issue.

I have managed to get serial to work, and can issue commands to the device. My issue is the following;

1. I fire up the shield.
2. Shield reports back CREG = 2 which means ME is looking for an operator to connect to.
3. Shield reports back CREG = 1 which means it has connected to an operator.

- Running AT+COPS? returns my provider, as long as CREG = 1.

4. Seconds in, CREG = 4, which means Unknown.

I don't see why it keeps disconnecting me, I have gone through 4 different SIM cards and the problem persists.

Has anyone else had this problem and if you did, how did you manage to work around it?

```
17:29:25.000 -> NORMAL POWER DOWN 
17:29:25.000 -> 
17:29:25.000 -> +CREG: 3
17:29:27.993 -> ?????????? (SHIELD TURNS ON, GARBAGE OUTPUT)
17:29:29.520 -> RDY
17:29:29.520 -> 
17:29:29.520 -> +CREG: 2
17:29:29.520 -> 
17:29:29.520 -> +CREG: 0
17:29:29.520 -> 
17:29:29.553 -> +CFUN: 1
17:29:29.553 -> 
17:29:29.553 -> +CPIN: SIM PIN
17:29:33.506 -> AT+CPIN=1234
17:29:33.506 -> 
17:29:33.506 -> OK
17:29:34.503 -> 
17:29:34.503 -> +CREG: 2
17:29:36.528 -> AT+COPS?
17:29:36.528 -> 
17:29:36.528 -> +COPS: 0
17:29:36.528 -> 
17:29:36.528 -> OK
17:29:38.022 -> 
17:29:38.022 -> Call Ready
17:29:39.550 -> AT+COPS?
17:29:39.550 -> 
17:29:39.550 -> +COPS: 0
17:29:39.550 -> 
17:29:39.550 -> OK
17:29:41.044 -> 
17:29:41.044 -> +CREG: 1
17:29:42.572 -> AT+COPS?
17:29:42.572 -> 
17:29:42.572 -> +COPS: 0,0,"CYTAMOBILE-VODAFONE"
17:29:42.572 -> 
17:29:42.572 -> OK
17:29:44.565 -> AT+COPS?
17:29:44.565 -> 
17:29:44.565 -> +COPS: 0,0,"CYTAMOBILE-VODAFONE"
17:29:44.598 -> 
17:29:44.598 -> OK
17:29:47.587 -> AT+COPS?
17:29:47.587 -> 
17:29:47.587 -> +COPS: 0,0,"CYTAMOBILE-VODAFONE"
17:29:47.620 -> 
17:29:47.620 -> OK
17:29:49.580 -> 
17:29:49.580 -> +CREG: 4
17:29:50.111 -> AT+COPS?
17:29:50.111 -> 
17:29:50.111 -> +COPS: 0
17:29:50.111 -> 
17:29:50.111 -> OK
```

Comment: 6 V on barrel jack or Vin of Mega is not enough

Comment: The mega is powered by the USB cable connected to my laptop. It's the SIM900 shield that is connected to the power supply.